# In AWS Kinesis, what happens if we call GetShardIterator with a stale/expired SequenceNumber?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Normally, we call [GetShardIterator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetShardIterator.html) with the SequenceNumber of the last read record (if our previous ShardIterator is expired).

It is assumed that the SequenceNumber belongs to a valid Record that is within the retention period (i.e. default 24 hours).

But what if it is outside of the Kinesis retention period (i.e. 25 hours ago)? Then that Record/SequenceNumber would have been deleted from the stream.

Will GetShardIterator throw an exception? [What kind of exception](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetShardIterator.html#API_GetShardIterator_Errors)? Or will it return no records?

Comment: Good question. My guess is that it will return the record at the trim horizon, because this is a likely condition and it isn't covered explicitly in the docs. Hopefully you'll know in another 10 hours ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was interesting enough to me that I tried it out.

TL;DR: it works as I expected: starting with a a sequence number that's past the trim horizon is equivalent to starting from the trim horizon.

To test, yesterday morning I posted a record on a dedicated stream:

```
aws kinesis put-record --stream-name test-expiration --partition-key irrelevant --data "this is a test"
{
    "ShardId": "shardId-000000000000",
    "SequenceNumber": "49616057638370363251266361760650016619879524195517857794"
}
```

Then I waited almost 24 hours (good thing I didn't decide to sleep in this morning), and ran [a utility that I wrote](https://github.com/kdgregory/aws-misc/blob/trunk/utils/kinesis_reader.py) to verify that the record was still on the stream:

```
> kinesis_reader.py test-expiration TRIM_HORIZON 1
{"SequenceNumber": "49616057638370363251266361760650016619879524195517857794", "ApproximateArrivalTimestamp": "2021-03-04T11:33:13.254000+00:00", "Data": "this is a test", "PartitionKey": "irrelevant"}
```

Lastly, I took the code from that utility, put it into a Jupyter Notebook, and executed it after the record hard been in the stream for more than 24 hours:

1. Retrieve the shard iterator:

   ```
   client = boto3.client('kinesis')

   stream_name = "test-expiration"
   shard_id = "shardId-000000000000"
   sequence_number ="49616057638370363251266361760650016619879524195517857794"

   resp = client.get_shard_iterator(StreamName=stream_name, ShardId=shard_id, ShardIteratorType='AT_SEQUENCE_NUMBER', StartingSequenceNumber=sequence_number)
   shard_itx = resp['ShardIterator']
   ```

   This returned an iterator (which I'll omit because it's a lot of opaque text). It was wondering it if would throw, but there's no documented exception corresponding to a stale iterator.
2. Use this iterator to retrieve records:

   ```
   client.get_records(ShardIterator=shard_itx)
   ```

   ```
   {'Records': [],
    'NextShardIterator': 'AAAAAAAAAAE8Pi3/Ykdggje538B61BxObso1tCZAK4MJIGMc//IGiqJlNdUz2PgTGXhMAW3GLJIFSsaSmWW72Y2qBuwk8+WvKse0Al8DhjBNUmCdB5T/FbUa/67NeUjgSsktcke3ZiCs+rnHXFkAv08rR8egQsJCDmcHkELeEKTaa5pnlMB9kUDB+NT+yFCO7oFNaDdz4OUSH094IN0+Y/w6n5K+XTLsVvhPmM6pYdTv2xllzJJnTA==',
    'MillisBehindLatest': 44741000,
    'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'fd58bcf1-6596-0186-a5e4-a7359063274d',
     'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
     'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'fd58bcf1-6596-0186-a5e4-a7359063274d',
      'x-amz-id-2': 'jK9tGfx5eSyi5ysHhnANVn0IvJrwWwYzbxRGTRyFnk1OgjfQ+D2KtzqfF3FXVg5wwBH0m/QBoXdwJ+cEQSeBCktkKgFWOUx5',
      'date': 'Fri, 05 Mar 2021 11:44:04 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
      'content-length': '315'},
     'RetryAttempts': 0}}
   ```

   As you can see, there are no records in the response.

   Surprisingly, it only indicates that I'm 44741000 milliseconds behind the latest record, which I added this morning. I would have expected something closer to 8640000 millis (one day).

As a final experiment, I wrote a loop that would count how many times I had to read the stream to find a record that I put on the stream this morning (which was, by now, a half hour old):

```
count = 0

while True:
    count += 1
    resp = client.get_records(ShardIterator=shard_itx)
    print(f"{count}: {resp['MillisBehindLatest']} millis behind latest")
    if resp['Records']:
        print(resp)
        break
    shard_itx = resp['NextShardIterator']
```

The answer: 99 reads, with the shard iterator advancing approximately 500 seconds each time.

I'm going to keep this stream around for a while: I want to see if Kinesis will update its internal pointers so that subsequent requests return a shard iterator that's closer to the present time.

**Update**

I ran through this code again, approximately an hour later than the first try. When I retrieved records using the iterator, it **incorrectly** told me that I was 0 milliseconds behind latest. A subsequent retrieve (using the iterator from the first) reported 49915000.

Moral: don't rely on `MillisBehindLatest` unless you've been actively processing records.

Comment: Wow! This is amazing sleuthing. Thanks so much for this detailed answer. It'd have been really great if this was mentioned in the Kinesis docs :).